# Error ID1039: The certificate's private key could not be accessed even when app pool account has access to private key

Tags: asp.net, iis, certificate, application-pool

After installing a `.pfx` cert into the 'Local Machine' store on my laptop, I configured an ASP.NET website in `IIS Manager` to use that cert in its https bindings.

The application pool, which the website uses, is assigned a user account that has access to the cert. When I navigate to the homepage of the site, I get a 500 error page. In Windows `Event Viewer`, the following is logged...

> Error: 'ID1039: The certificate's private key could not be accessed.
> Ensure the access control list (ACL) on the certificate's private key
> grants access to the application pool user

This is driving me nuts because, as I mentioned previously, the app pool account already has `Full Control` and `Read` permissions granted against the cert in the `Local Machine` store.

I have already tried the suggestion mention on this webpage...

https://elybob.wordpress.com/2012/07/04/wif-error-id1039/

whereby you grant the IIS_IUSRS account `Read` permissions against the MachineKeys folder, but that made no different to my situation.

I'm stuck on how to make progress here, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This error indicates that your application pool does not have permission to access the certificate private key, and you need to allow your application pool to access the certificate private key. The same problem exists in this blog, you can refer to it: https://ninjanichols.com/2012/10/error-id1039-the-certificates-private-key-could-not-be-accessed/

Comment: @DingPeng Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I have triple-checked that the app pool user does have permissions to access

Comment: Turn out, I was given the wrong cert to reference in my ASP.NET website, lol. After installing the correct cert, the website started to work. I'm glad the answer was this easy, otherwise I was starting to think I had a very edge case issue lol.

Answer (score 2):

In IIS, to be able to use Certificates from file (Certificate .pfx file), need to set "Load User Profile" to True in the application pool's Advanced Settings to be able to load a cert by filename & password.

Select Application Pool of your ASP .NET application -> Right Click -> Advanced Settings -> Set **Load User Profile** to True

For cryptographic operations, Microsoft algorithms may not be FIPS compliant and you may override it by setting Security Policy to support Digital Signature verification in

Administrative Tools -> Tools -> Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> System Cryptography: Use FIPS Compliant algorithms -> Disabled

Update: Using certificate private key may also require permission to IIS application pool:

Run certlm.msc -> Select certificate -> All task -> Manage private key
-> Give permission to application pool

Comment: I checked the `Load User Profile` setting for the app pool in question, and it is set to `true`.

Comment: @Jason Evans, I have updated answer to add steps to give permission to Private Key for IIS AppPool, please check if it helps.

Comment: Excellent. It is worth pointing that out for anyone else who ends up on this question.